# How to write RegEx for inserting line break for line length more than 30 characters

Tags: regex

I am using a text editor which lets me use regular expressions to find/replace text. I have a large text file and  want to insert a new line in lines which are more than 30 characters. I want the line to break after the 30th character and it doesn't matter if a word or phrase breaks or not.

Original text:

```
Hi this is a sample text.
this is a line.
This is a very very very very very long line.
This is a regular line.
....
```

Modified text:

```
Hi this is a sample text.
this is a line.
This is one very very very ver
y very long line.
This is a regular line.
....
```

How can I write a regular expression to:

1. find lines with more than 30 characters.
2. insert a new line AFTER the 30th character of the lines which are more than 30 characters long.

Comment: which programming language ?

Comment: The correct answer lies here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59413771/regexp-break-long-lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find what:

```
^(.{30})
```

Replace with:

```
\1\n
```

Comment: or `^.{30}\K`, replace with `\n`

Comment: I'd ditch the ^ so that you can match parts of a line (useful to e.g. split a 90-character line into three parts).

Answer (score 0):

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elviz/wL7ob8ox/1/):

```
var txt1 = "This is a very very very very very long line."
var txt2 = txt1.slice(0, 30) + " \n" + txt1.slice(30);
alert(txt2);
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasnt looking for doing it in JS (or any other programming language), read the question.