# How to break long lines into five-character lines

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I want to break long lines into five characters and ignore short lines:

```
aaa
bbbbbbb
cc
dddddddddddd
```

into

```
aaa
bbbbb
bb
cc
ddddd
ddddd
dd
```

I found way to find only long lines:

```
^(.{5,})
```

but I've no idea how to break it to five character lines several times.

Another way is: find `.{0,5}(\s*|$)` and replace with `$0\n`. It works but after each previous line it creates a new empty line, even after short lines.

I'm testing in Sublime Text 3, so maybe some Sublime plugin could do it as well?

Comment: Do they have to break on consecutive characters like only `ddddddddd` or just 5 characters?

Comment: How quickly this was marked as a duplicate when this is an entirely different question. `line length more than 30` where the answer is `^(.{30})` a single match per line with an anchor that guarantees a line oriented result. In fact that answer was wrong, as it doesn't break long lines into pieces. This is the real answer. This should not be marked as a duplicate ! Now the real answer is buried.

Comment: Btw, who marked this as a duplicate ? Probably -  Possible [duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390629/should-stack-overflow-remove-the-regex-tag).

Comment: It's not duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972991/how-to-write-regex-for-inserting-line-break-for-line-length-more-than-30-charact. Cause there it break lines only once after first 30. In my case I need line break every 5 characters, so x15's answer perfectly fits.

Comment: So how to remove duplicate status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A line break can be inserted like this :

Find `([^\r\n]{5})` replace `$1\r\n`

https://regex101.com/r/dTeMbq/1

Comment: No-assertions way works excellently! Do I need some additional tuning to make assertions works?

Comment: `(?<=[^\r\n]{5})` is trickier. The problem is that the current position is only advanced 1 character, but should be advanced by 5. This can be seen here https://regex101.com/r/Lcppi8/1